# REST with JAX-RS : extending Application class with @ApplicationPath on Tomcatv7.0 gives 404 error

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I am learning REST web services with JAX-RS.

below are the two classes I have written :

```
package com.vitp.app;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApp extends Application {

}
```

And

```
package com.vitp.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/t")
    public String doTest()
    {
        return "test success";
    }
}
```

I am deploying this WebApp with Tomcat v7.0.

when I trying to access URL: http://localhost:8080/RestAdvance/api/test/t I get 404 error. 
Not able to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: What jars (or dependencies) are you using? Edit your post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `ResourceConfig` and register your `Test` class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {
public MyApp () {       
        register(Test.class);       
    }
}
```